# Framework Error when Google SignIn Firebase by idToken Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

i have a problem when i want to login using googleSignIn with Firebase in flutter.
for the first signin, i save idToken and accessToken to sharedpreferences, but when i try to call idToken and accessToken in SplashScreen, i got Framework Error.

this is my code that i use in splashScreen :

```
Future<void> loginGoogle() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      idToken = pref.getString("idToken");
      accessToken = pref.getString("accessToken");
      loginStatus = pref.getInt("loginStatus");
    });

    print(idToken);

    if (idToken != null || idToken != "") {
      AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          idToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken);

      AuthResult result = (await auth.signInWithCredential(credential));

      user = result.user;

      if (!user.isEmailVerified) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Login()), (route) => false);
      } else {
        print("berhasil login");

        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Home()), (route) => false);
      }
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Login()), (route) => false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: all of my provider error, materialApp error,. framework Error it says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the `signInSilently()` instead. That way you don't need to save the token which is a better practice.
The `signInSilently()` allows you to sign in a previously authenticated user without interaction.

```dart
Future<void> loginGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signInSilently();

    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );

      AuthResult result = (await auth.signInWithCredential(credential));

      user = result.user;

      if (!user.isEmailVerified) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Login()), (route) => false);
      } else {
        print("berhasil login");

        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Home()), (route) => false);
      }
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Login()), (route) => false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you bro for your answer. it's nicely working.